# Отличия NestedScrollView от ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

В чем отличия `NestedScrollView` от `ScrollView`, если можно на примерах.
 Спасибо

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NestedScrollView` поддерживает скроллинг вложенных в него элементов. [Пример](http://ivankocijan.xyz/android-nestedscrollview/)

Так же он используется (если требуется) при реализации всяких выезжающих (анимированных) тулбаров, FAB-кнопок и прочей анимации на фоне скролящихся элементов. [Пример](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/design-library-part-3/)